# Ternary Operator makes html closing tags not visible

Tags: php, html, ternary-operator

I'm creating a very basic and simple validation for empty fields using the ternary operator.

Code:

```
<?php
    echo "<span class='error'>" . $error = (isset($_POST['naam']) && empty($_POST['naam'])) ? 'Required field' : test_input(isset($_POST['naam'])) . "</span>"
?>
```

Whole line

```
echo "<div class='form-group'><Label for='name'>Voorstelling naam</Label><input type='text' name='naam' value='".$row['naam']."' placeholder='Naam'><span class='error'>" . $error = (isset($_POST['naam']) AND empty($_POST['naam'])) ? 'Dit is een verplicht veld' : test_input(isset($_POST['naam'])) . "</span></div>";
```

The code is working fine but the `</span>`tag is not working/visible in the browser

Comment: What's your output, when you look at View Source in your browser?

Comment: As an aside, I'd  suggest wrapping the entire ternary and assignment in brackets, just to make reading easier for what's concatting, where and to what.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing an assignment and string concatenation. Can you post the whole line of code please?

Comment: Sorry my Code is indeed incomplete.. I edited my post

Comment: @KevinStich Sorry my code is indeed incomplete.. I edited my post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With your updated code, try just removing the `$error =` assignment portion. You're also passing the `isset` return value into `test_input` which may not be what you want.

Because of the ternary in the `$error =` assignment, the `"</span></div>"` is only being appended to the failure case of the check.

```
echo "<div class='form-group'><Label for='name'>Voorstelling naam</Label><input type='text' name='naam' value='".$row['naam']."' placeholder='Naam'><span class='error'>" . 
    $error = (isset($_POST['naam']) AND empty($_POST['naam'])) ? 
        'Dit is een verplicht veld' : // No added "</span></div>" here, doesn't close!
        test_input(isset($_POST['naam'])) . "</span></div>"
;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed only appending the span closing tag in the failure case of the check ;)

Answer (score 1):

You code seems incomplete to me.

You can add PHP code INSIDE HTML :

```html
<!-- PHP INSIDE HTML -->
<span class="error"><?php echo (empty($_POST['naam']))? "Required field" : test_input($_POST['naam']); ?></span>
```

OR generate HTML INSIDE PHP :

```html
<?php
// HTML INSIDE PHP
$html = '<span class="error">'
      . (empty($_POST['naam'])? "Required field" : test_input($_POST['naam']))
      . '</span>';
echo $html;
?>
```

**Additionnal notes :**

1 - I think you don't need to test `isset` and `empty` because `empty` return `true` if variable doesn't exist and i believe you want to display error also if field is not transmitted right?

2 - And you don't need to use `isset()` inside your call to `test_input()` function because if your script reach this step, you already know that `$_POST['naam']` exist and is not empty, and by doing it, you will use the return of isset as argument instead of the actual value of the field.